# Can Lookup Column be displayed?

Tags: lookup-column, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

I use Cross-site publishing in SP13, create a authoring site and a intranet(display site.) I have created a list of content including a lookup column for contact person; look up from another Contact list. However, I was able to use CSWP to display everything but the contact lookup column. How can I troubleshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but you have to do the mapping for the managed property and crawled property yourself.

SharePoint does not automatically create managed properties for the following column types:

- Lookup
- Calculated
- Task outcome
- Summary Links data
- Rich media data for publishing